# Polymorphic cross-associations on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, polymorphic-associations

OK, this is an interesting and most importably **real urgent problem** for me to solve... In order for others to neatly comprehend it, I've stretched myself to make a well illustrated post.

---

### The Object Model

So I have this simple, easy and "beautiful" model in mind. See the first picture. (You can ignore `PathEntry`, it's not relevant in my situation.)

The idea is that a `MediaFeedItem` owns:

- a collection of `ThumbnailFileEntries` (accesible through the *ThumbnailFiles* property)
- at most 1 **raw** `FileEntry` (*MetadataFile* property) and
- at most 1 `MediaFileEntry` (*MediaFile* property)

We shall refer to these last three entity types as the *file entities*.

Now there's more: As you can see, I am inheriting both `ThumbnailFileEntry` and `MediaFileEntry` from `FileEntry`, **and let's not debate that!** (for now), it's one of those end-of-story aspects of the design and both entity types will continue to grow later on.

[image: EDMX Model Diagram]

This already brings me some significant issues right away in regards to the polymorphic associations induced by the relationships from the *file entities* to `MediaFeedItem`.

The first thing that you shall observe is that I have eliminated the navigation property from the **derived** *file entities* (`ThumbnailFileEntry` and `MediaFileEntry`) to the primary entity `MediaFeedItem`.

[image: MediaFeedItem_MediaFile association]

I do this because they already inherit that property defined in the base class `FileEntry`. As you can see, I do not delete the roles at the end of these associations.

[image: MediaFeedItem_MetadataFile association]

---

### The Relational Model

I shall be using the so-vastly-conceptually-superior TPT strategy for generating and mapping my Object Model to the RDB world (vs TPH/TPC).

I'm using EF5-rc, the EDMX model designer to design my model, and the EF5 DbContext Generator to generate a DbContext and POCOs cuz I wanna use the DbContext API.

As you can see, I can nicely generate the database model using the EF tools:

[image: DB Model Diagram]

---

### The Problem

When loading a new MediaFeedItem and saving it, I get the following error:

**System.InvalidOperationException: Multicplicity constraint violated. The role 'MetadataFile' of the relationship 'MediaFeedModel.MediaFeedItem_MetadataFile' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just to clarify, you are adding a brand new MediaFeedItem and getting this error? can you please breakpoint just before SaveChanges and tell me whats in each of the nav properties (ie MetadataFile, ThumbnailFiles and MediaFile)

Comment: Why does it *"nicely"* create the database? The DB schema is totally wrong, isn't it? You have one-to-many relationships in the schema while your EF model has one-to-one... How did you create this schema? Using `DbContext`? Did you remove or change the connection string or remove the EDM section of the connection string and remove the `UnintentionalCodeFirstExeception` from `OnModelCreating`, i.e. did you convert from Model-First to Code-First?

Comment: Also: *"I have eliminated the navigation property from the derived file entities...* **because** *they already inherit that property defined in the base class"*. This might not be the reason of your problem, but: The two removed properties belong to different associations than the nav. property in the base class. By removing them the base property does not become the nav. property for the other two associations and it does not replace the removed properties. A single navigation property cannot be part of more than one relationship.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments, it was long weekend in Canada and, well.. I really needed it. In regards your first comment @Slauma, the the DB uses 1-* in order to implement  1-0..1 (there is a FK relationship, but arguably I don't see anything that prevents multiplicities other than 0..1 on the DB end.) I did not create the schema using DB context, as I said, I first generate it using EDMX and generating DB with the EF wizard.. then I generate DbContext (to code with it).

Anyhow, I thing you're definitely right on the issue in your second comment.. Will comment more below.

Comment: Can you show the code for "*When loading a new MediaFeedItem and saving it*" which causes the exception finally? I'm also confused that a one-to-one relationship in your EDMX creates a one-to-many relationship with a foreign key in the DB when you generate the schema from your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your problem one thing stands out, The FK relationship between File and MediaFeedItem is required (IE a file must have a MediaFeedItem), but in the case where you are in an extended version of File you probably dont want this.

What i think you want to do is one of the following:

- change the multiplicity on MediaFeedItem_FileEntry to 0..1 - 0..1 so that it isnt required at either end
- create a new extended type to handle your metadataFile type and remove the direct reference between the base type and MediaFeedItem

I personally think the second is a more elegant solution to your problem as its creating an actual type for your MetadataFile

What appears to be happening is that you are trying to create an extended type but the base type isnt actually a metadata file.

Comment: So, yeah, I heard you both and as a matter of fact, it's pretty evident that the problem here is my erroneous, original, assumption that I could "share" the same navigation property for different relationships. Breaking into these entities prior to `SaveChanges()` showed that the "owning" `MediaFeedItem` had been reset to `null` for all but the last _file entity_ added to the graph. Moreover, even when keeping both navigation properties, the inherited relation was not set unless I explicitly did so. I will need to do some re-factoring as suggested.