# Cascading deletes on *Derived Entities*

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

OK, check out the following simple object model:

- Entity `ConcreteThingy` derives from `AbstractThingy`.
- Entity `Owner` can have at most 1 `ConcreteThingy`.

  - No two `Owners` can have the same `ConcreteThingy`.

**EDMX:**

[image]

**DB model (TPT):**

[image]

### What I want:

I want 2 things, in descending order of priority:

- **Thing I want #1:** Above all, I want the simplest, most concise, cleaner solution to #2
  below.
- **Thing I want #2:** When I delete an `Owner`, I want to automatically delete any potentially associated `ConcreteThingy`, **along with the base `AbstractThingy`.**

### What I'm doing:

So, *naturally*, I went to the EDMX and simply turned on *Cascade delete* on the **Owner 0 ↔ 0..1  ConcreteThingy** association.

[image]

This works well in setting the Delete rule of the `FK_ConcreteThingy_Owner` relationship to *Cascade*, but I don't see ANY constraints/DB code that makes sure that the `AbstractThingy` record gets deleted as well.

[image]

Again, when I delete an `Owner`, the corresponding `ConcreteThingy` (if any) is deleted, but it leaves the dangling `AbstractThingy`, which not surprisingly, I don't want.

**Can somebody please tell me what is the standard way to implement this type of tasks using EF 5?**

I've tried by making `AbstractThingy` abstract, hoping that the SQL code would somehow infer what I want (understandably there would be some sort of chicken-and-egg conundrum for the generator, but hey, at least I tried it.)

Or should I define some sort of smart-ass referential constraint in my EDMX?

Or is it expected that I'd go to the DB and write code myself, like a trigger, etc...!?!? That would be a bit of a[nother] fiasco for EF and its design tools.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you reverse the 'abstract' and 'concrete' classes? Have abstract be FK'd to owner, and concrete FK'd to abstract? Then a series of cascading deletes will work. This also might help to normalize the 1:1 'abstract' to 'concrete' construction in this design.

Comment: I know what you mean, but here's the tricky catch: **the design is intentionally that way.** This is the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11270620/1426433

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9071945/270591 That was for EF 4.x. I guess the situation didn't change with EF 5.

Comment: @user15741: Write it as answer or comment to that question. I didn't ask it and the question owner doesn't notice your comment here.

Comment: Sorry, saw the comment response and thought it was you.

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064273/cascade-delete-in-entity-framework-table-per-type-inheritance. Btw. You could just replace association between Owner and ConcreteObject with association between Owner and AbstractObject (or perhaps create AbstractOwner that owns AbstractObject)

Comment: It is indeed a question that one finds coming up but somewhat rarely: @Slauma mentioned that post as well (to the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9071945/1426433).

I must insist that **the design is intentionally that way**; this example is a purposely artificial, but that was in order to keep it concise. You can look at a realistic example (and why the design is the way it is,) in http://stackoverflow.com/q/11270620/1426433.

There, the conclusion was that I cannot really use base classes effectively due to a great awful lot of impedance mismatch between EF and the DB world.